# JBOSS 7, avoid security checks and alerts

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I would like to know how to avoid or delete all the Vulnerability alerts that Jboss is giving me.
I want to disable ALL vulnerability alerts.

Which configuration file should I change and how?

Comment: You would have to give more details. It is very difficult to know what you are asking without details if th#e alerts

Comment: Vulnerabilities like:Vulnerability: HTTP port 7003 unprotected JBoss Management Interface GET
/jmx-console/
ToDo: Secure or remove access to the JMX and/or Web Console
CertRef: 
Tool Reference: Nessus 23842
Comment: The remote web server allows unauthenticated access to an
administrative Java servlet Counted in: 2013-12
Monitor: 
NessusOutput: 
CVE: 
i want to avoid all these checks...

Comment: AS7 doesn't have jmx-console... you sure you are using AS7?
Also mgmt interface in AS7 is not on port 7003...